# How to fix label when I hover mouse over map made with tmap

Tags: r

I plotted a map of Puerto Rico with poverty rate data by county (municipalities) using tmap. When I turn the interactive version on, I am able to click on the municipality and the correct data show up.

However, when I hover my mouse over the municipalities, Puerto Rico's FIPS code (72) shows up in a white box. How can I change it so when I hover my mouse over the municipality, its name shows up instead of the 72?

```
#Create map plot
    PRmap2 <- tm_shape(PRmap) +
      tm_fill("Pobreza",
          popup.vars = c("Municipio" = "COUNTY", "Pobreza (%)" = "Pobreza",
                       "Ingreso per cápita ($)" = "Ingreso_per_cápita"),
          title = "Pobreza (%)",
          style = "pretty",
          breaks = c(-Inf, 0, 20, 40, 60, Inf)) +
      tm_style(c("col_blind")) +
      tm_borders() +
      tm_layout("Pobreza en Puerto Rico",
        legend.title.size = 1.5,
        legend.text.size = 0.6,
        legend.position = c("left","bottom"),
        legend.bg.color = "white",
        legend.bg.alpha = 1)

#Visualization mode changed to view so we can interact
tmap_mode("view")

#Interactive visualization
PRmap2 + 
  tm_basemap(server = "OpenStreetMap.HOT")
```

You can find the interactive map here:
http://rpubs.com/Javier_927/461125

Comment: Please, could you share your `PRmap` object ?

Comment: @MarcoSandri, I'm new to R. What to you mean by sharing my PRmap object?

Comment: Save `PRmap` on a `.Rdata` file using `save` and then share the file using for example FileDropper. See here for details: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15821/stack-overflow-etiquette-for-sharing-files-and-resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the order of your dataframe, it uses the first column to determine the hover over text.  There should be a more direct way to assign it, but this at least works.

Answer (score 13):

You can set the "id" in tm_polygons:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tmap/versions/2.2/topics/tmap_mode

```
tm_polygons("income_grp", palette="-Blues", contrast=.7, id="name", title="Income group")
```